# Angular Kendo UI Grid column not display data conditionally

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, conditional-formatting

I do not want to display data into a cell if the value returned from database is -1. The cell allows in-cell editing. If any other value is returned then it should display. And the cell should still retain its value in case we want to save it again.
In order to achieve that, I am trying to set the color of the cell to white/Transparent if value is -1. And it does that when value comes back to grid. But when I click in that cell it displays -1. So I call it again from cellClickHandler, but does not solve the purpose.
Is there any better way so that value is just not displayed when -1? OR if someone can guide me to correct color issue when clicked inside cell. Here is my code:

```
html:        
<kendo-grid-column field="MasterID" width="75">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <span class="whole-cell" [style.color]="colorTransparent(dataItem.MasterID)">
                    {{ dataItem.MasterID }}
                </span>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>

//in component
    public colorTransparent(MasterID: number): SafeStyle {
        let result;

        switch (MasterID) {
            case -1:
                result = '#ffffff'; //white
                break;

            default:
                result = '#808080'; //grey
                break;
        }

        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(result);
    }

  //when you click a cell to edit
    public cellClickHandler({ sender, rowIndex, column, columnIndex, dataItem, isEdited }) {
        this.colorTransparent(dataItem.MasterID);

        if (!isEdited && !this.isReadOnly(column.field)) {
            sender.editCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, this.createFormGroup(dataItem));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to allow users to edit that specific field? If not, then you can continue with the setup you have and conditionally add the class `"k-grid-ignore-click"` to the cells that have a value of -1. This will prevent users from clicking on the cell to reveal the `-1` value.

For more info on this, I'd check out the Telerik documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/).

**EDIT:** If you still want to allow users to edit that field, I would suggest setting up a service to pull in data and format it. That way you could map any values in this particular field that come in as `-1` to `null`. When you save the data back to the db, map all values that were not altered from `null` back to `-1`

Comment: Yes, they can add value the field and save again

Comment: In that case, I would suggest setting up a service to pull in data and format it according to your needs. For this issue in particular, map any values in that field that come in as `-1` to `null`. Then when you save the file the data back to the db, map all values that were not altered from `null` back to `-1`.

Comment: Great! Will add edit to answer so it can be selected. Good luck!